# Python synchronization between multiple processes, wait for each other to continue

Tags: python, multithreading, process, synchronization

This is a very basic implementation of what I am actually trying to do. I have a method like this:

```
def method():
    print "starting..."
    # do some processing

    # at this point, I want to pause the process until all the processes
    # have reached this point and then continue with the rest of the method

    # continue with more processing
```

I am using `multiprocessing.Process` to create 5 threads which will execute this method.

So, what can I do to synchronize the execution of the 5 threads? is this possible? I investigated a little bit of Semaphore and Event but I don't really know how to implement them.

Comment: Are you using the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module? Have you looked at [`Process.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join) or [`Pool.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.join)?

Comment: @jdehesa yes, I am using multiprocessing and I am using `Process.join`. I am thinking now that maybe I should split the method in more simpler methods and use `join`

Comment: Oh sorry I misread the initial question, I though you wanted to pause until all processed had finished, not until they all reached some point. Then it is not `join` what you need.